# ssh and bring up many processes in parallel + solaris

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ssh

I have many processes and each of them take a lot of time to come up (5-10 min).

I am running my script in abc@abc1 and ssh to xyz@xyz1 to bring up the daemons.

There in the other machine(xyz@xyz1) I want to bring up 10 processes in parallel (call there startup scripts). 
Then after 10 min I will check there status are they up or down.

I am doing this because I want the execution time of (my) script to be minimum.

How to do this using shell script with minimum amount of time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get your processes started:

```
for cmd in bin/proc1 bin/proc2 bin/procn; do
    logfile=var/${cmd#bin/}.out
    ssh xyz@xyz1 "bash -c '$cmd > $logfile 2>&1 &' && echo 'started $cmd in the background. See $logfile for its output.'"
done
```